# Determining linear independence of a set of functions

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

I have the set $S = \{\cos(2t), 1, \cos^2(t)\}$ and I am trying to determine whether or not it is linearly independent.

This is linear algebra review for my ordinary differential equations class, but I can't remember how to go about this. My professor gave us an example where we had two elements: we write them as a linear combination and set that expression to $0$ and then take the derivative of both sides so that we have two equations and two unknowns. We then take $t=0$ and solve the system for $c_1$ and $c_2$. If $c_1 = c_2 = 0$, then we know the set is linearly independent. In this case, we have three elements, so do we take the second derivative in addition to the first derivative?

After I did this, I achieved the following equations:

\begin{cases}
    c_1\cos(2t)+c_2+c_3\cos^2(t) = 0\\
    -2c_1\sin(2t) - 2c_3\cos(t)\sin(t) = 0\\
    -4c_1\cos(2t) - 2c_3(\cos^2(t)-\sin^2(t)) = 0
\end{cases}

And then when I take $t=0$, the second equation basically just becomes $0=0$ which is useless.

In the end, I get

\begin{cases}
    c_1+c_2+c_3 = 0\\
    -4c_1-2c_3 = 0
\end{cases}

But now I have 2 equations with 3 unknowns. Is this sufficient to say that it is not linearly independent? Or is there another strategy that I can use?

Comment: Yes, based on the Wronskian.

Comment: They are not independent. Simply use the formula for $\cos 2t$: $$\cos 2t - 2 \cos^2 t +1 = 0$$

Comment: Yep, I just realized that after I posted this. Simply writing $\cos(2t)$ as a linear combination of the other elements shows that $S$ is not linearly independent. Thank you! Is it possible, though, to use the strategy which involves taking derivatives of the linear combination and taking $t=0?$

Comment: That can prove linear independence but can't prove linear dependence. The Wronskian is the preferred method of determining linear (in)dependence.

Comment: Interesting. The theorem in my book says the following: Suppose $W(f_1,f_2,...,f_n) \neq 0$ for some $t_o \in I$. Then $\{f_1, f_2, ..., f_n\}$ is linearly independent. It seems based on this theorem that the Wronskian method is only conclusive when the Wronskian is nonzero. So then we do in fact know that the set is linearly dependent when the Wronskian is identically 0?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Write the equation above as
$$\pmatrix{\cos(2t)&1&\cos^2 t\cr -2\sin(2t)&0& 2\sin t\cos t\cr -4\cos(2t)&0&\cos^2 t - \sin^2 t\cr} \cdot \pmatrix{c_1\cr c_2\cr c_3\cr}=\pmatrix{0\cr 0\cr 0\cr}.$$
If the matrix $A=\pmatrix{\cos(2t)&1&\cos^2 t\cr -2\sin(2t)&0& 2\sin t\cos t\cr -4\cos(2t)&0&\cos^2 t - \sin^2 t\cr}$ is invertible, the only solution is $\pmatrix{c_1\cr c_2\cr c_3\cr}=\pmatrix{0\cr 0\cr 0\cr}$ and the functions are linearly independent. (And the other way around; if $A$ is not invertible, the functions are linearly dependent.)

You can test for invertibility by finding $\det A$ -- the Wronskian -- which after some trigonometric identities, reduces to $0$.